# Views exposed filter: Upcoming/Past events

Tags: 7, views

I want to implement an exposed filter in the view with a date field. I want to show two choice in select list according to the date value (upcoming events/past events). But I don't know how to achieve this using date field because it allows to choose date only.
Is there any way to achieve this feature?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Add a date filter.

Expose the date filter.

Select the grouped filters option

[image]

Scroll down and define your filters as shown in next image

[image]

And you are good to go. You will have an output like this

[image]

You can change the options to make it a drop-down too.

To fix for the UI bug in exposed filters groups:

Make sure your date module is at Version: 7.x-2.9 or later, then apply the patch exposed_grouped_filter-1876168-71.patch (https://www.drupal.org/node/1876168#comment-10344663)

Comment: Thank you Gokul.
Can I ask you a question? Which version of views are you working on because I have option to select date and relative date but no place to input the value.

Comment: I am using Views 7.x-3.5

Comment: I am also using the same version but I am having problem in UI. Screenshot: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=cf1e32c5f0c9e63a&id=CF1E32C5F0C9E63A!217#cid=CF1E32C5F0C9E63A&id=CF1E32C5F0C9E63A!218

Comment: From the operator dropdown select less than or greater than options, and then add the labels accordingly. That should work.

Comment: I had the same problem in UI. 
After a lot of attempts tried to save the grouped filter as following:
1. Created the view filter and saved with the 3 initial group items with random labels (as those cannot be removed in first save).
2. Removed the group items in next save and added one with relative value now.
3. Saved the view.
4. Added the 2nd group item to the filter. The relative date input still does not appear but for some reason it took the value now.
5. Saved the view.

More saves of view or re-edits in filter may be needed in between.

Comment: If this does not work for you, try either to display the hidden relative day input with your browser developer tools or to export the view and manually edit the relative date value.

Comment: Works on Drupal 9

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 3 default options (hit "Remove" link) and add them manually by using the button "Add another item".
The new options will now display the field for relative date.

Hope that helps

Best

EDIT: that seemed to work but actually not... Sorry